# Selenium not finding particular elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm attempting to navigate to the 'People' section after performing a flickr.com search (https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=lake).

I'm unable to find elements within `<div id="content">` (6th line from top in HTML image). Essentially whatever I try, a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown.

```
#! python3

# Saves photos to file from flickr.com using specified search term

import logging
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import sys

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s - \
%(levelname)s - %(message)s")

def flickr_images():
    try:
        search_term, number_images = sys.argv[1:]
    except:
        print("Something went wrong. Command line input must be of \
    format: 'filename searchterm numbermessages'")
        return

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.flickr.com/")

    # wait for page to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(\
        (By.ID, "search-field")))

    # find search text field and input search term
    driver.find_element_by_id("search-field").send_keys(search_term)

    # find and click search button
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-icon-button").click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

    content = driver.find_element_by_id("content")
    content.find_element_by_class_name("search-subnav-content")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   flickr_images()
```

[image]

Comment: One question:
Shouldn't it be 'driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-subnav-content")' instead of 'content.find_element_by_class_name("search-subnav-content")'?

Comment: What you expect `WebDriverWait(driver, 5)` to do?

Comment: Wrong member and  sub member. Can't handle a subclass if not grab main_class.

Answer (score 2):

I would navigate directly to the search results page and *wait for the results to appear*:

```
driver.get("https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=" + search_term)

# wait for the search results to appear
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "search-photos-results")))

content = driver.find_element_by_id("content")
content.find_element_by_class_name("search-subnav-content")
```